# What defines a message as 'cached' in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

As we all know, in the change from `v11` to `v12`, cache was introduced, however I can't find anything online that explains exactly what it is as a concept. Can anyone explain how it works?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the cache gets built up by the bot once it's started. So anything that was there before it was started is "uncached" but you can use raw events to get things like reaction adds to these.

Comment: I figured this was the case, I'm going to take a look at the djs src on github to see if its commented on in any more detail there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just taken a look at the D.JS source and thankfully it is heavily commented.

In many files it suggests that any message that is sent by a user, or any message mentioning a user caches said user. This works in the same way with guilds I believe.

This means that in order to find a user in a server using `#get` or other fetch methods, the user must have been mentioned, or typed a message.

[BaseManager.js source file here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/src/managers/BaseManager.js)

[Client.js source file here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/src/client/Client.js)

[GuildManager.js sournce file here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/src/managers/GuildManager.js)